# Find and Edit few lines in json file

Tags: json, batch-file, command-line

We have one json file (PFB) from application side and we want to change few line in that json file. This file is present on every user's machine and its located in their profile.

```
"restartReason":  null,
"currentWebLanguage":  "en-US",
"appPreferenceSettings":  {
                              "openAtLogin":  true,
                              "openAsHidden":  "False",
                              "runningOnClose":  true,
                              "registerAsIMProvider":  "False"
                          },
"isLoggedOut":  false,
"pastModernAuthSucceeded":  true,
"previousWebClientVersion":  "27/1.0.0.2019031417",
"isForeground":  false,
"notificationWindowOnClose":  true,
"isAppSessionEnd":  true,
"isAppTerminated":  false,
"rendererCrashInfo":  null
```

In "appPreferenceSettings" we need to change to below

"appPreferenceSettings":  {
                              "openAtLogin":  true,
                              "openAsHidden":  "True",
                              "runningOnClose":  true,
                              "registerAsIMProvider":  "True"
                          },

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Regardless of your off topic question, I would advise you to pick a scripting language that has a method to read and write JSON.  Batch files would have to brute force it because it just sees the file as text.